# Don't understand why I can't call setCentralWidget in QMainWindow subclass

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

`//clposter.h
class CLPoster : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT`

public:
    CLPoster();

private slots:
    QWidget createCentralWidget();
    void createActions();
    void createMenu();
    void createStatusBar();
    void loadSavedPosts();
};

`//clposter.cpp
CLPoster::CLPoster()
{
    setWindowTitle("Craigslist Poster");`

```
QWidget mainWidget = createCentralWidget();
setCentralWidget(mainWidget);
```

//    createActions();
//    createMenu();
//    createStatusBar();

//    loadSavedPosts();
//    checkForActionsNeeded();    //May want to break up into more functions
}

The error I'm getting is this:

> /usr/include/qt4/QtGui/qwidget.h:: In constructor ‘CLPoster::CLPoster()’:
>
> /usr/include/qt4/QtGui/qwidget.h:787: error: ‘QWidget::QWidget(const QWidget&)’ is private
>
> /home/brett/projects/CLPoster/CLPoster-build-desktop/../CLPoster/clposter.cpp:9: error: within this context
>
> /home/brett/projects/CLPoster/CLPoster-build-desktop/../CLPoster/clposter.cpp:10: error: no matching function for call to ‘CLPoster::setCentralWidget(QWidget&)’
>
> /usr/include/qt4/QtGui/qmainwindow.h:141: candidates are: void QMainWindow::setCentralWidget(QWidget*)

I'm having trouble interpreting the error message. It says there is no matching function call, but it should be inheriting it from QMainWindow. It could just be a lack of understanding C++ more so than QT, first time I've used it, but dunno. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All QWidget items must be allocated in the free-store (`new`) since they all have to have "parents".  In Qt a parent will delete its children (with `delete`).  This is why any function returning, accepting, whatever a widget is going to do so on a pointer to a widget, not the widget itself; you need to do the same.

Comment: Arg, I meant to make a pointer (in fact have done so many times in the past) but left off that little `*`. The copy constructor should have been my clue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The [setCentralWidget](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qmainwindow.html#setCentralWidget) function expects that you are sending a **pointer** to a QWidget (`QWidget*`), whereas you are trying to send the actual object (or a reference to the object, `QWidget&`, as implied by the compiler error) in your code. If you create your central widget as a pointer (change the member function to `QWidget* createCentralWidget()`) and pass the pointer to the setCentralWidget function you should be good to go.

e.g.

```
QWidget* CLPoster::createCentralWidget()
{
   QWidget* w = new QWidget;
   // Do stuff..
   return w;
}
```

Then in your constructor, you can just call `setCentralWidget(createCentralWidget())`. The QMainWindow destructor will ensure that your central widget is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need to allocate the Widget on the heap and pass a pointer to setCentralWidget()